# How to compile a java program with imported classes?

Tags: java, compilation, classpath

I am trying to get started with the API of the java software weka. I wrote the following code for testing:

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class hello_weka {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/aljoscha/Masterarbeit/weka_examples/iris.arff"));
      Instances data = new Instances(reader);
      reader.close();
      // setting class attribute
      data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() -1);
      System.out.println(data);
      System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

It works fine when I execute it in Eclipse.
However I can't get it to run in the Terminal.

I tried to provide the .jar path during compilation and then execute the program from the directory of the compiled class.

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar hello_weka.java
java hello_weka
```

This approach does not work, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/core/Instances
>       at hello_weka.main(hello_weka.java:8)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.core.Instances
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
>       ... 1 more

What am I doing wrong?

I guess I am doing just some completely stupid stuff since I just start to code in Java. If so, please excuse me and try to tell me how I can do better.

**Edit:**

when I try the thing proposed in the answers I get the following Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hello_weka
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello_weka
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
>   Could not find the main class: hello_weka. Program will exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer: The answer of dunni is nearly correct. For me it works if I provide the classpath of both, the jar file and the classfile, but separated by a `:`.

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar:/home/aldorado/myjavascripts/ hello_weka
```

Is it possible that this differs depending on the OS / JDK you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

> java -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar hello_weka

Comment: There are some problems with your class dependencies. Make sure that you have provided correct path to the jar file in your classpath (-cp)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the classpath to your JAR also when executing the program:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar hello_weka
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add also the current directory (where your own classes are stored) to the classpath:

```
java -cp .;/usr/share/java/weka.jar hello_weka
```

Comment: That looks somehow better, however I get another error, this one seems to be about the syntax. So do I need to specify the directory containing the own class or the class itself? I will try to work this out...

Comment: i found the solution. Posted it below.